# Simatic IoT 2000 SSL/TLS connection

Tags: node.js, azure, yocto, node-red

We are trying to connect an IoT Gateway (Simatic Iot 2000) to Azure, for first instance de use a Flow in Node-RED to connect to Azure and it works but only from PC and Raspberry PI when I try to do this from Simatic with (that has Linux Yocto) it doesn't work, I'm almost sure that problem is about certificates, I try with OpenSSL to connect to azure thorugh MQTT o HTTPs and it works but from Node Red and node.js I cant't connect. I've reviewed this error with Wireshark and it seems like a connection problem and Azure sent me a FIN flag and everything stop. I have read that Linux Yocto doesn't include all certificates to set a correct SSL connection

[Wireshark connection from Simatic Iot 200 to Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSEhj.png)

Comment: Can you not setup a test where you check the correct SSL connection without node-RED and maybe also without azure ?  This way you know that node-RED and/or azure is not the problem.

Comment: I would also dive deeper into the Linux Yocto certificates issues you have mentioned : on the internet you might find some helpful information.